# Trouble with Python Code. Objective is to code suffix during input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Objective: Write a function that takes an integer as its only parameter and returns the ordinal abbreviation for that integer as its only result. For example, if your function is passed the integer 1 then it should return the string "1st". If it is passed the integer 12 then it should return the string "12th". If it is passed 2003 then it should return the string "2003rd". Your function must not print anything on the screen.

```
def convert (n):
    self.num = num
    n = int(self.num)
    if 4 <= n <= 20:
         suffix = 'th'
    elif n == 1 or (n % 10) == 1:
         suffix = 'st'
    elif n == 2 or (n % 10) == 2:
         suffix = 'nd'
    elif n == 3 or (n % 10) == 3:
        suffix = 'rd'
    elif n < 100:
        suffix = 'th'
    ord_num = str(n) + suffix
    return ord_num

def main ():

    day = int(input("Enter the day:"))
    month = int(input("Enter the month:"))
    year = int(input("Enter the year:"))

    print("on the %n" %n, convert(day), "day of the %n" %month,
          convert(month), "month of the %n" %year, convert(year),",
          something amazing happened!")

    main()
```

This is my code however it keeps saying I haven't defined n when I run it. But above I've already defined it so not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably closer to what you want:

```
def convert(n):
    n = int(n)
    suffix = ''
    if 4 <= n <= 20:
         suffix = 'th'
    elif n == 1 or (n % 10) == 1:
         suffix = 'st'
    elif n == 2 or (n % 10) == 2:
         suffix = 'nd'
    elif n == 3 or (n % 10) == 3:
        suffix = 'rd'
    elif n < 100:
        suffix = 'th'
    return str(n) + suffix


def main ():
    day = int(input("Enter the day: "))
    month = int(input("Enter the month: "))
    year = int(input("Enter the year: "))

    print("on the %s day of the %s month of the %s, something amazing happened!" %
          (convert(day), convert(month), convert(year)))

main()
```

There are few issues. You cannot use `n` in `main()` when you define it in `convert()`. Also `%n` is not a valid format character. You need to define `suffix = ''` when also want run the year through the conversion function as the year can be larger than 100. Also, you probably copied the code from within a class definition. I removed the `self`.

Comment: This makes so much more sense now! I never knew that about n in main()Thank you so much, Mike!!

Comment: Good to hear that it helped. You can accept an answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  to indicate that it solved your problem.